# "as if he had been" or "as if he were"

Tags: subjunctives, modality

G. H. Hardy, "A Mathematician's Apology":

> Even in mathematics, history sometimes plays strange tricks; Rolle figures in the text-books of elementary calculus **as if he had been** a mathematician like Newton;

Can I substitute the past perfect for plain past simple and say **as if he were**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the phrase *as if he were*, *were* is not a ‘past simple’, although it looks like it, and in *as if had been*, *had been* is not a perfect, although it looks like one.

These are both *irrealis* or ‘unreal’ uses of the past forms of *be* and *have*. *Were* here is irrealis **present** tense, and its past form is **had been**.

This is explained in more detail [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13258/32), section 2.3.

Consequently, you cannot substitute *were* in referring to Michel Rolle, because that is present tense and Rolle has been dead for almost 200 years.